# Good Tutorial To Learn C++ Development For Game Boy

Tags: c++

I'm learning *C++* with this book of Deitel: [*C++ How to Program, 5/e*](http://www.deitel.com/books/cpphtp5/) and some tutorials and resources of the internet, but I want to learn how I can develop *Nintendo GameBoy Advance* games using *C++*, but only in resources over the internet, because I don't want to spent money now with a thing that I only want to try.

Comment: Will you be writing GBA games after you've completed your OS and compiler or before?

Comment: @William no no, he has to finish his MMO first!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get [DevkitPro](http://www.devkitpro.org) and a good library like [TONC](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text). Also, you can get more help at [GBADev](http://forum.gbadev.org).

Although you can use C++ in GBA development, plain C is recommended. The choice is yours to make, though.

Comment: Well, there's a lot of extra overhead on the whole classes thing. It's easier to just call Damage(theKid, 20) than to call theKid.Damage(20), where thisEntity is an instance of one class, which is based on another, which is the one that actually holds the Damage method. But that's just like, my theory, man.

Comment: Classes add very little overhead compared to good C.  None if you keep them simple.  They also can have less overhead than poor C. Virtual inheritance for instance is hard to emulate in C.  What _does_ add overhead is C++'s exception model.

Comment: And if you keep them simple enough to add (virtually) no overhead, you might as well go full out Wolf3D, which I based my example on.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try wxwidgets its very helpful. Here is a big picture of a simple game:

- **gameEngine class** (responsible for creating sprite(s), setting up the environment, checking for key i/o, monitor various statistics of the game eg score, how many tries etc)
- **Sprite Class** (it will monitor things like life, health, direction etc)
- **Hero** -> Inherits from sprite class with some of its own functionality.
- **Enemy** -> Also inherits from sprite class.
- **Fire** -> Inherits from sprite as well.

Comment: You could also set up a net in your back yard. Then model the **projectile**.  Decide if you're going to play **volleyball** or **badminton** and make the appropriate class either **ball** or **birdie** (which should inherit from projectile). The **actionator** is a good base class from which you can derive both **hands** for volleyball, and **racket** for badminton. In each round of the game, alternate the use of actionator until the projectile hits the ground. If you want you can also derive **gameboy** from projectile and throw it out the window, much as your answer has done... :-)

Comment: This was years ago--I don't even remember writing the comment--but I'm pretty sure I didn't downvote you! Just made fun of you a little bit *(but I've gotten on people's case for doing similar things. So I will be contrite and apologize for having done so)* But the point embedded in the ribbing is that it's so abstract as to be unhelpful...like if you read a recipe for "Chicken in Savory Lemon Sauce" giving extremely detailed instructions about how to open the oven yet cultivates with "Make Savory Lemon Sauce. Combine with Chicken. Enjoy!" The question asks about the Gameboy; *specifics* help.

Comment: no wonder you are a hostilefork ;) lol. Now that I look at my answer it does seem kinda silly. I really don't care about down vote, it is just a number but if it is done with an explanation then at least the person can improve in future. You don't have to apologize I should be thanking you for teaching me :)